# Module of prestashop and webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, prestashop

I need to create prestashop module with webpack and vueJS, but I can't find a way how to set it together. The starting file in prestashop is modulename.php, and start file in webpack is index.html. And I don't know how to connect it. Even if I try include index.html to my main module file, then I don't have virtual-tags and nothing created via vueJS (I build production).

There's some way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on that, and came up with something I'm not really happy with, but maybe it can help.

Inside the module folder, I've created a vue project with vue-cli + webpack-manifest-plugin in a subfolder 'A'.

I use this vue project in a specific page of my module, which is served by this controller :

```
<?php
class mymodulepageModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        $manifest = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../../js/A/dist/manifest.json');
        $json = json_decode($manifest, true);

        foreach ($json as $original => $compiled) {
            if (substr($original, -3) === '.js') {
                $uri = '/modules/mymodule/js/A/dist'.$compiled;
                $this->registerJavascript(sha1($uri), $uri, ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 80]);
            } elseif (substr($original, -4) === '.css') {
                $uri = '/modules/mymodule/js/A/dist'.$compiled;
                $this->registerStylesheet(sha1($uri), $uri, ['media' => 'all', 'priority' => 80]);
            }
        }

        $this->setTemplate('module:mymodule/views/templates/front/page.tpl');
    }
}
```

In `mymodule/views/templates/front/page.tpl`, you can now use vuejs components.

```html
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='content'}
  <div id="app"></div>
{/block}
```

The drawbacks I see with this :

- I use compiled assets : it can quickly be painful to build for every change. And you loose the debug possibility with the vue toolbar.
- Parsing the manifest.json file on every request is suboptimal.
- How will it behave if prestashop also load vuejs on the same page. I'm affraid of potential conflicts here.